# Styling a FormHelper multiselect checkbox

Tags: cakephp, formhelper

I had this multiple checkbox:

`<?php echo $this->Form->input('Power', array('type'=>'select', 'multiple' => 'checkbox', 'options' => $poderes, 'label' => false)); ?>`

Thats generate this HTML:

```
<div class="input select"><input type="hidden" name="data[Power][Power]" value="" id="PowerPower"/>

<div class="checkbox"><input type="checkbox" name="data[Power][Power][]" value="1" id="PowerPower1" /><label for="PowerPower1">Negociacao</label></div>
<div class="checkbox"><input type="checkbox" name="data[Power][Power][]" value="2" id="PowerPower2" /><label for="PowerPower2">Comerciais</label></div>
<div class="checkbox"><input type="checkbox" name="data[Power][Power][]" value="3" id="PowerPower3" /><label for="PowerPower3">Compras</label></div>
</div>
```

I want to put a `title`in the `<div class="checkbox">` and change the class. I tried many ways and is not working.

How i do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**TLDR:**

Write manually with PHP `foreach()`

**Explanation:**

Remember, CakePHP is just PHP, so look at the field names / ids...etc it auto-generates when you do a `$this->Form->input()`, and just build a `foreach()` loop that writes out your checkboxes in whatever manner you want.  Voila!

CakePHP is awesome for so many things, but every once in awhile you need enough customization that you just need to fall back to good ole' PHP instead.